# How to fetch data using React query

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

SampleApi.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "sample";
const TOKEN = "sample";

const SampleApi = axios.get(BASE_URL, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
  },
});

export default SampleApi;
```

useSample.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import SampleApi from "../api/SampleApi";
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "react-query";

export const useSampleGet = () => {
    const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery({
        queryFn: () =>
          fetch(SampleApi).then((res) => res.json()),
      });  
      return { isLoading, error, data };
};
```

Trying to console log

```
  const { data: sampleData } = useSampleGet;
  console.log(sampleData);
```

I want to fetch data using React query. I tried reading the documentation but it is still not working.

I want to console log sampleData, It always show undefined:

[image: Undefined]

Comment: Have you checked that you actually get something from your api call ?

Comment: And `useSampleGet` is a function, better to call it: `useSampleGet()` ;)

Comment: if you get something from the query, then also check it is valid json. e.g. {"x":"Hello World"} is valid, "Hello World" isn't. You can just check with a browser

Answer (score 0):

This is an invalid call to `useQuery`:

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery({
  queryFn: () =>
    fetch(SampleApi).then((res) => res.json()),
});
```

you need to pass at least a `queryKey` to `useQuery`:

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['sample'],
  queryFn: () =>
    fetch(SampleApi).then((res) => res.json()),
});
```